# Modal popup using angular 1.6 component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angular. The version of angular I am using is 1.6. I need to show a popup to display some data and fetch results back. Is it possible to create a separate component for that popup modal or is there any plugin available. I am not able to use any bootstrap or material css. Please suggest me a sample

Comment: Check for [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)

Comment: @KaustubhKhare  I am not able to use any material css,only custom css

Comment: are you facing any issues while using the external libraries?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure  No, but my client is not supporting it

Comment: @AA what do you mean by client?

Comment: The person who asked me to do this

Comment: @AA is he told not to use external libs or he has given you his design of UI?